# Not able to write If condition in DisplayTag

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, displaytag

I want to apply if condition on data retrieved through list onto JSP page using DisplayTag
Suppose We have a list object `'Alist'`. This object is a part of DisplayTag table. Table has pagination enabled.

```
<display:table class="displayTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Alist" name="Alist" pagesize="20" requestURI="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Action.do?csrf=<%=csrfPage%>">
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="both" />
```

Now in this we have display tags like below :

```
<display:column class="normal_text" property="NUMBER" title="Number" />
```

Now I would like to change value of property `NUMBER` based on various conditions. I am new to DisplayTag. Please guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can go like :
For single condtion :

```
<c:if test="${<your_condition>}">
    <display:column class="normal_text" property="NUMBER" title="Number" />
</c:if>
```

For multiple conditions :

```
<c:choose>
      <c:when test="${<condition_1>}">
       <display:column class="normal_text"property="NUMBER"title="Number"/>
      </c:when>
      <c:when test="${<condition_2>}">
         <display:column class="normal_text"property="NUMBER"title="Number"/>
      </c:when>
      <c:when test="${<condition_3>}">
         <display:column class="normal_text"property="NUMBER"title="Number"/>
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
         <default display if none of your condition was true>
      </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Where c is the prefix that you defined in your jsp page for JSTL tag lib.

Comment: Thanks Rajnikant.
My condition is ${AList.NUMBER == '919019029039'}. But it is not working. I can see both if conditions working. Why so?

Comment: Can you share the code that you have prepared? So I can have proper idea. Sorry for late reply, I was on lunch break.